# android: tablelayout span element across 2 rows? programatically

Tags: java, android, mobile, sdk, tablelayout

Imagine you have a tablelayout in this 3x3, id would be like:

```
11 12 13
21 22 23
31 32 33
```

Now you got all those different cells, is there a way you could span 11 and 21 programatically?

Comment: `TableLayout` does not support spanning rows. `GridLayout` does, though I have not tried changing one at runtime.

Comment: are you sure about that?, just read gridview doesnt and tablelayout does..

Comment: "are you sure about that?" -- very.